# eclipse problems pushing and run apk on mobile phone

Tags: android, apk, adt

a few month ago I wrote a radio station app for android phones. I tested it in the emulator and on my phone and all worked fine, when I pushed it directly from eclipse to the phone.

Now I wanted to make some changes to the app and finalize it, but my problem is now that I can't run it again from Eclipse on the phone.

When I test in the emulator all is fine. If I copy the APK from hand to the phone an install it, all is fine.

In Eclipse the console tells me that:

```
[2011-10-11 11:51:30 - Radio54House] Android Launch!
[2011-10-11 11:51:30 - Radio54House] adb is running normally.
[2011-10-11 11:51:30 - Radio54House] Performing com.Radio54House.Radio54House activity launch
[2011-10-11 11:51:32 - Radio54House] WARNING: Unknown device API version!
[2011-10-11 11:51:32 - Radio54House] Uploading Radio54House.apk onto device '0288424643204157'
[2011-10-11 11:51:32 - Radio54House] Installing Radio54House.apk...
[2011-10-11 11:51:32 - Radio54House] Success!
[2011-10-11 11:51:32 - Radio54House] Starting activity com.Radio54House.Radio54House on device 0288424643204157
[2011-10-11 11:51:32 - Radio54House] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2011-10-11 11:51:35 - Radio54House] Starting activity com.Radio54House.Radio54House on device 0288424643204157
[2011-10-11 11:51:36 - Radio54House] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2011-10-11 11:51:39 - Radio54House] Starting activity com.Radio54House.Radio54House on device 0288424643204157
[2011-10-11 11:51:39 - Radio54House] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2011-10-11 11:51:42 - Radio54House] Starting activity com.Radio54House.Radio54House on device 0288424643204157
[2011-10-11 11:51:42 - Radio54House] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2011-10-11 11:51:45 - Radio54House] Starting activity com.Radio54House.Radio54House on device 0288424643204157
[2011-10-11 11:51:45 - Radio54House] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.Radio54House/.Radio54House }
[2011-10-11 11:51:45 - Radio54House] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2011-10-11 11:51:45 - Radio54House] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.Radio54House/com.Radio54House.Radio54House} does not exist.
```

This is the second day I was searchin google without a result. The only thing I found some people who wrote to clean the project first, but that didn't help me.

If needed here is also my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.Radio54House"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Radio54House"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  >
            <intent-filter>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RadioTab" />
    <activity android:name=".NewsTab" />
    <activity android:name=".ChartGroup" />
    <activity android:name=".ChartSelector" />
    <activity android:name=".House27Tab" />
    <activity android:name=".ClubFuelTab" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try restarting your device? 
I think I had this errormessage too, and I tried restarting the device and uninstall the app manually on the device. Maybe it works...

Comment: yes, I already tried to restart my mobile. The apk is also deleted on the phone. 

If I install the apk by hand and try to update it via Eclipse all seems to work fine, the app starts but the apk isn't updated. 

I have the feeling this is a read/write permission problem. 

For additional infos I use:
`Eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 2; Build id: 20110218-0911
Android SDK R13 
Android SDK R12 plugin for Eclipse`

Comment: Today I made a test with another mobile phone and on this it works fine. So it seems to be a problem with my mobile. My LG Optimus 2x mobile is rooted with SuperOne Click, perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: Now it's working. I made a softwareupdate from V10C to V10D and now all is fine.